# R separating out 3 linear regression components from a mixture

Tags: r, classification

I created a dataframe dfall containing 3 linear regression components

```
x1=runif(50, min=0, max=100)
e1=runif(50, min=0, max=10)
y1 <- 0.2*x1+10+e1
y1


plot(x1,y1,col="blue")


df1 <- data.frame(x=x1,y=y1)
df1$ID <- 1
df1$col <- "red"


x2=runif(25, min=0, max=100)
e2=runif(25, min=0, max=5)
y2 <- 0.7*x2+15+e2
y2


plot(x2,y2,col="blue")


df2 <- data.frame(x=x2,y=y2)
df2$ID <- 2
df2$col <- "green"


x3=runif(35, min=0, max=100)
e3=runif(35, min=0, max=15)
y3 <- -0.5*x3+30+e3
y3


plot(x3,y3,col="blue")


df3 <- data.frame(x=x3,y=y3)
df3$ID <- 3
df3$col <- "blue"


dfall <-rbind(df1,df2,df3)
dfall
dfall <- dfall[sample(1:nrow(dfall)), ]
dfall

plot(dfall$x,dfall$y,col=dfall$col)
```

I then tried to separate the linear regression components using kmeans:

```
fitkm <- kmeans(dfall[,c(1:2)], 3) 

dfall <- data.frame(dfall, km=fitkm$cluster)
dfall
```

However I got quite poor classification results:

```
table(dfall$ID,dfall$km)
```

Is there a better way of accurately separating out the 3 linear regression components?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I feel like this question might be better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Kmeans creates clusters based on distance from points (centers). Density based clustering algorithms arre better suited to solve your problem. Try using GMM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example you may want to look into finite mixture models, which would enable you to recover the parameters in your underlying regressions and the classifications. Here is an example with your data:

```
library(mixtools)
mixmod <- regmixEM(dfall$y, dfall$x, k=3)
summary(mixmod)
```

The output gives you the proportions of each type of observation and the coefficients - lambda is the mixture proportion, beta1 the intercept and beta2 the coefficients. The match to your simulated data is pretty good:

```
summary of regmixEM object:
          comp 1    comp 2    comp 3
lambda  0.315816  0.457191  0.226992
sigma   3.758362  2.463029  1.259267
beta1  36.675001 14.031268 17.338412
beta2  -0.507215  0.213874  0.699148
loglik at estimate:  -357.4478
```

The assignment of an observation to a given category is stored in the `mixmod` object in a matrix of probabilities in `mixmod$posterior`. If we extract the assigned class and compare it to the true class the fit is pretty good (bear in mind the names assigned to classes by the mixture model are arbitrary, here comp 1 is ID 3 obvs, etc.):

```
predclass <- unlist(apply(mixmod$posterior, 1, function(x){names(which.max(x))}))
table(dfall$ID, predclass)
   predclass
    comp.1 comp.2 comp.3
  1      2     48      0
  2      0      0     25
  3     31      4      0
```

There is a nice overview and explanation of mixture models and their implementation in R [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBzIKRtuLRAhUnJsAKHWNOD_QQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv032i06%2Fv32i06.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGHJJnai-7jZ9qDrjnVVd0w4isrbg).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to determine optimal k if this is unknown?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but I can't claim any special expertise about these models. Since you are generating predictions for $y$ I would use cross-validation to try to select a reasonable value of $k$. There is a good chapter on these models in Cosma Shalizi's Advanced Data Analysis from an Elementary Point of View for which there is a free pdf copy online you can find and I'm pretty sure he has worked examples in R of doing exactly that.